# Unable to create Sitecore user for an Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory-module

we have Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 150812) with Active Directory Module 1.3, it all seems to be working correctly and I checked the documentation for the module and our configuration seems to be working correctly. I can see the existing Active Directory users and Roles using the User and Role manager but when we try to create a new user of the domain "ad" we get the following error:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean 
   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_security_createnewuser_createnewuser_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8ecf017a\aa20fcab\App_Web_3rvdpsoq.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

 Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
 Message: Access is denied.

 Source: Active Directory
   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()
   at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at LightLDAP.SitecoreADMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String userName, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9.<CreateUser>b__8()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Connectivity seems to be working as when accessing /sitecore/admin/ProviderStatus.aspx we get this

[image: providerstatus.aspx]

### Update

Our configuration for Membership Provider is the following

```
<add name="ad"
 type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADMembershipProvider"
 connectionStringName="xxx"
 applicationName="sitecore"
 minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
 connectionUsername="xxx"
 connectionPassword="xxx"
 connectionProtection="Secure"
 attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
 enableSearchMethods="true"
 customFilter="(memberof=CN=JIRA Users,ou=Groups,ou=Information 
 Services,ou=Strategy &amp; Finance,ou=Head 
 Office,DC=ENTITY,DC=COM,DC=AU)"/>

 <add name="ad" 
  type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADRoleProvider" 
  connectionStringName="EndeavourLDAP" 
  applicationName="sitecore" 
  username="xxxx" 
  password="xxxx" 
  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
```

Comment: Check whether connectionUsername and connectionPassword are correct in your "ad" provider under Membership and also username and password in your as provider under RoleManager

Comment: Do you have any custom filter set in your membership "ad" provider?

Comment: Please update your question with all configuration for membership and role providers with obfuscated password and usernames just to see your current setup

Comment: @PeterProchazka thanks for the prompt answer, I've updated my question

Comment: Can you try to remove customfilter from membership provider and try once again?

Comment: @PeterProchazka I tried removing the custom filter but the same error messages continues

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 8.0 you may want to double check the version of the AD module.  I believe that version 1.2 supports up to 8.1.  Version 1.3 is for version 8.2

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory.aspx